# hide vtkBoxWidget2 handles

Tags: c++, vtk

I have a vtkboxWidget2, all I want to do is to hide the handles of two opposite sides (any 2 circles of the same color in the attached photo).

[image]

I've looked but didn't find a way to do so, I can either hide or show **all** handles without the ability of specifying a certain one.

is there a way to do so ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Set this

```
vtkBoxRepresentation::SafeDownCast(boxWidget->GetRepresentation())->HandlesOff();
```

Comment: Thank u for the answer, but this hides all handles, I'm looking for a way to hide some handles, not all of them.